# Sniff 3rd Party Page, Check/Insert Data using ASP.NET into Database and Then Display Results

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, bookmarklet

I have been tasked with reading information from a table on a 3rd party page. The website will have multiple pages and thus will have to have the bookmarklet run on it once per page. I currently have the bookmarketlet pulling the data, and putting it into a pipe delimited array. I would like to send this pipe delimited array to a server side function that, in case of injection, sanitizes the data and then checks if it exists in a temp table, if it doesn't exist the the table, then insert.

After all of that is said and done, the script will send information about what happened during the server side scripting and the results will be presented to the user on the web page where the bookmarklet was executed.

I have looked into JSON, AJAX, and JavaScript as possible solutions to submit and work with data(Which I quickly detoured away from).

I am limited to using Microsoft solutions because of the environment I am working in.

So my question is, what would be best and how would I go about this? I have been unable to understand or execute any of these solutions.

What would be be most efficient way to post data to a database and get a response in a Microsoft environment using a bookmarklet on a 3rd party page, and get a response that the user sees?

Comment: Your question is much too open ended. I doubt you'll get much response. Start your google search with `bookmarklet scrape`. BTW, you can't "detour away" from JavaScript if you intend to write a bookmarklet.

Comment: I meant that I detoured away from submitting data with JavaScript exclusively due to the security issues with it. I do agree the question is quite a bit open ended, but I am unsure on how to progress. I'll tried to clarify.

Comment: If the response data doesn't need to be used directly within the 3rd party page, only be shown to the user, then the most simple solution is to open a new window like `window.open('http://someurl.tld/?data=...')`. Only slightly more complex: create an iframe within the page with `src="http://someurl.tld/?data=..."`